# Горизонтальные пункты меню на сайте

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5

Как реализовать косые пункты меню на сайте[image: Это меню из игры]

Comment: <map> <area> как вариант.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если кратко, то используйте `transform: skew()`

Пример [codepen](http://codepen.io/kazzkiq/pen/qEMjaw)

```css
body {
  font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background: tomato;
}
.skew-menu {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 9em;
}
.skew-menu ul {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  transform: skew(-25deg);
}
.skew-menu ul li {
  background: #fff;
  float: left;
  border-right: 1px solid #eee;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #555;
  font-weight: bolder;
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
}
.skew-menu ul li:first-child {
  border-radius: 7px 0 0 7px;
}
.skew-menu ul li:last-child {
  border-right: none;
  border-radius: 0 7px 7px 0;
}
.skew-menu ul li:hover {
  background: #eee;
  color: tomato;
}
.skew-menu ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 1em 2em;
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
  transform: skew(25deg);
}
```

```html
<nav class="skew-menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Shoes</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Sandals</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Shirts</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Jackets</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 2):

через `transform: skewX(-20deg);` Элементы меню у Вас скорее всего `li`, вот ему и дайте `transform: skewX(-20deg);`. А на элемент с текстом `transform: skewX(20deg);`, так вы выровняете текст. Только не давайте `transform: skewX(20deg);` на тег `<а>`, так как уголки будут нажимать соседнюю кнопку